# How to get data from a related table in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get data of an animal through a relationship with the user table

Here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Animal;
use App\Clinic;
use App\Role;
use App\Slaughter;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class ClinicController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()

    {

        $farms = User::where('role_id', 3)->get();
        $user = Auth::user();
        $animal = Animal::all();
        return view('clinic.index', compact('user', 'animal', 'farms'));
    }
 public function show($id)
    {
        $farm = User::query()->findOrFail($id);
        return view('clinic.show', compact('farm'));
    }
```

While getting the user which is Farm in my case, I would like to get the animals the farm admin registered through this relationship

```
Model

class Clinic extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

From My tinker, the relationship is working perfectly
Here comes my index page

```
@extends('layouts.app')

 @section('content')
 <br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <div class="container">
       <div class="row justify-content-center">
             <div class="col-md-20">
                   <div class="card">
                         <div class="card-header">
                               <center>
                                     <h1>Clinic Dashboard</h1>
                               </center>
                         </div>

                         <div class="card-body">
                               @if (session('status'))
                               <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                     {{ session('status') }}
                               </div>
                               @endif

                               <center>
                                     <h2>Welcome! <strong>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</strong></h2>
                               </center>
                               <hr>
                               <br>
                               <div class="container box">
                                     <div class="table-responsive">
                                           <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="background: white">
                                                 <thead>
                                                       <tr>
                                                             <th>Farm Id</th>
                                                             <th>Farm Name</th>
                                                             <th>Action</th>
                                                       </tr>
                                                 </thead>
                                                 @foreach( $farms as $farm)
                                                 <tbody>
                                                       <tr>
                                                             <td>{{ $farm->id }}</td>
                                                             <td>{{ $farm->name }}</td>
                                                             <td><a href="/clinic/{{ $farm->id }}"><button
                                                                               class="btn btn-outline-primary">View Farm
                                                                               Animals</button></a></td>
                                                       </tr>
                                                 </tbody>
                                                 @endforeach
                                           </table>
                                     </div>
                               </div>

                         </div>
                   </div>
             </div>
       </div>
 </div>

@endsection
```

And my `route`

```
Route::get('/clinic/{farm}', 'ClinicController@show');
```

And finally the show `view` where I am getting all the errors

```
 @extends('layouts.app')

 @section('content')
 <br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <div class="container">
       <div class="row justify-content-center">
             <div class="col-md-20">
                   <div class="card">
                         <div class="card-header">
                               <center>
                                     <h1>Farm Dashboard</h1>
                               </center>
                         </div>

                         <div class="card-body">
                               @if (session('status'))
                               <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                     {{ session('status') }}
                               </div>
                               @endif

                               <center>
                                     <h2>Welcome! <strong>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</strong></h2>
                               </center>
                               <hr>
                               <br>
                               <div class="container box">
                                     <div class="table-responsive">
                                           <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="background: white">
                                                 <thead>
                                                       <tr>
                                                             <th>Id</th>
                                                             <th>Animal Type</th>
                                                             <th>Sex</th>
                                                             <th>Farm</th>
                                                             <th>Clinic</th>
                                                             <th>Vaccination</th>
                                                             <th>Nutrition</th>
                                                       </tr>
                                                 </thead>
                                                 @foreach( $farm as $farm)
                                                 <tbody>
                                                       <tr>
                                                             <td>{{ $farm->animals->id }}</td>
                                                             <td>{{ $farm->animals->type->category }}</td>
                                                             <td>{{ $farm->animals->gender }}</td>
                                                             <td>{{ $farm->animals->user->name }}</td>
                                                             @if(! $farm->animals->clinic)
                                                             <td>N/A</td>
                                                             <td>N/A</td>
                                                             <td>N/A</td>
                                                             <td>
                                                                   <a href="/clinic/{{ $farm->animals->id }}/create">
                                                                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                                                               Attach Clinic Detail
                                                                         </button>
                                                                   </a>
                                                             </td>
                                                             @elseif( $farm->animals->clinic)

                                                             <td>{{ $farm->animals->clinic->user->name }}</td>
                                                             <td>{{ $farm->animals->clinic->vaccination ?? 'N/A' }}</td>
                                                             <td>{{ $farm->animals->clinic->nutrition ?? 'N/A'}}</td>

                                                             <td>
                                                                   <a
                                                                         href="/clinic/{{ $farm->animals->clinic->id }}/edit">
                                                                         <button type="button"
                                                                               class="btn btn-primary">Edit Animal
                                                                               Clinic details</button>
                                                                   </a>
                                                             </td>
                                                             @endif
                                                       </tr>
                                                 </tbody>
                                                 @endforeach
                                           </table>
                                     </div>
                               </div>
                         </div>
                   </div>
             </div>
       </div>
 </div>

 @endsection
```

I hope I have provided all the fields that could be generating errors. Any assist will be kindly taken as it is a very important project for me
The error I am getting is

> Trying to get property 'animals' of non-object

Comment: How is the relationship working with `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`? can anybody explain this?

Comment: That what the User model provided. And I used the auth command for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this setup allows you to get all the animals of all the users of a specific clinic.  I leveraged route/model binding on your show() method too. Whatever ID you pass in the URL it will automatically load the clinic up.

```
// app/User.php

class User extends Autheticatable
{

  public function animals()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Animal');
  }

  public function clinic()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Clinic');
  }

}
```

```
// app/Clinic.php

class Clinic extends Model
{
  public function users()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
  }
}
```

```
// app/Animal.php

class Animal extends Model
{
  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
  }
}
```

```
class ClinicController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('auth');
  }

  public function show(Clinic $clinic)
  {   
    return view('clinic.show', compact('clinic'));
  }
}
```

```
// view
@foreach($clinic->users as $farm)

  @foreach($farm->animals as $animal)

    {{ $animal->name }} - {{ $animal->weight }} etc...  

  @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: I will have a problem when there will be 0 records in clinic

Comment: Use @forelse to deal with empty result sets on the view: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#loops -- or do away with route/model binding.

Comment: Now am getting this error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: When you did away with the r/m binding did you bring back your findOrFail() method? Also did you update your migrations to make sure these relationships have their foreign key columns?

Comment: Thank you that was the prollem

Answer (score 1):

In your view you have `@foreach($farm as $farm)`

What you need: `@foreach($farms as $farm)`

Edit: this only addresses part of the issue, upon closer inspection your relationships are out of whack, I'll see if I can whip something up.

Comment: Had a little chuckle from your name, nice!

Answer (score 0):

To get the related Animals for the $farm I would go

```
public function show($id)
{
    $farm = User::with(['animals'])->findOrFail($id);
    return view('clinic.show', compact('farm'));
}
```

Then in your blade

```
@foreach($farm->animals as $animal)
 {{ $animal->id }}
@endforeach
```

This is assuming you have your animal relation set in your user model of course which would be something like

```
public function animals()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Animals')
}
```

(All untested)

Comment: Now the problem is with my relationship. Could you look at my index method with the first eloquent

Comment: In your index you should just grab the user with relations as in FAKETAXIs answer. You can then loop through each relation like he has in the view.

Comment: It would be considerably less confusing if you didn't decide to refer to users as farms half-way through ;)